# Flash File Too Large - Won't Publish

Tags: flash-cs5

I have a 105 mb flash .fla file that needs to be published. It used to publish fine, but after a bit of tweaking, it cannot publish at all. The flash application would crash. I would assume this occurs from the sheer size of the file.

Is there any workaround? A third-party flash compiler perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that the only way to solve this problem is to save the file, move it to a different location on your hard drive, and then open it again. This solution has worked for me multiple times.